# What does it mean a power series converges in this situation?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity, power-series

I have this power series,

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$

I apply the root test as such,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left(  \frac{x^{n}}{\ln (n)} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{x}{1}= x$$

So the radius of convergence is $r=1$. since $ |x|<1$ has to hold.
But I get asked to show that the power series doesn't converge at $x= -r$. But does converges at $x=r$. And show the powers series's sum function $f$ is continuous at this interval $[-r:r)$

My answer: (I changed my anwser after being told it didn't make sense)
I have to find how the power series behaves at
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1^{n}}{\ln (n)}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln (n)}$$

If we assume this is true( I don't how to prove it for now),

$$\ln(n) \leqslant n$$

Then,

$$\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{\ln(n)} $$

since this is $\frac{1}{n}$ a p-series where $p=1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1}}$$

We know that a p-series diverges $p\le1$

we can conclude that,

$$0\le\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{\ln(n)} $$

so the series diverges at $x=r=1$

lets look at $x=-1=-r$,

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln (n)}$$

The alternating series says for,

$$\sum_{n}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}a_{n}$$
if
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } a_{n}= 0$$
and
$$a_{n+1}\leqslant a_{n}$$

the series converges,

Let's take the limit,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(x)} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

and this is true,

$$\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\leqslant  \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$$

so the series converges at $x=-r=-1$.
This I do this right now?

And how do I show that the series is continous in $[-r:r)$

Comment: My answer to your two "can I say that" is: it makes no sense, for numerous reasons.

Comment: If you can't tell the reasons. How would I know ?

Comment: Two many. E.g. we don't have "since −1<1 is true the series converges". Look at the definition and main property of the radius of convergence of a power series.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? I'm just lost here. $|x|<1$ means for any x in [-1:1) the series converegences right?

Comment: Or just help me with one mistake

Comment: For a real number $x$, $|x|<1$ only means $-1<x<1.$ The series converges for such $x$'s and diverges for $|x|>1.$ For $|x|=1$ we know nothing *a priori*.

Comment: @HamsaAhmedMohamed: Most of what you wrote is nonsense because you seem to be mixing evaluating the series with the calculation of the radius of convergence

Comment: @AnneBauval Can I use your last comment as an answer. Or do I have to a test for $|x|=1$.

Comment: There is no general "test" for $|x|=r$. You have to study specifically that precise series at $x=1$ and at $x=-1$ (separately).

Comment: See this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: (But see it later, once you know the behaviour of $\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{\ln n}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you

Comment: @AnneBauval That's right. First this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test and this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc and Hamsa: yes, or (at $x=1$) the (sadly) more known [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

Comment: @AnneBauval That's may be a nice  trap for the asker: the antiderivative of $1/\log x.$ Unless you apply comparison test additionally.

Comment: Yes, your (less overused) method is far safer and beautiful. @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: @AnneBauval I think it's right now.

Comment: Well done! And for the continuity, look at Abel's theorem (link in one of Ryszard's comments 8 hours ago).